# Why are all of my records not showing?

Tags: php, mysql

I have more than one article stored in my database, that I want to display. However, only the most recent article is being displayed on the page, rather than all of them. Any help to show all the articles would be appreciated.

```
 <div class="column-center">

     <?php
                 include 'includes/connect.php';

   $select_news = "select * FROM news";

   $run_news = mysql_query($select_news);

   while ($row_news=mysql_fetch_array($run_news)){
       $article_id = $row_news['article_id'];
       $article_title = $row_news['article_title'];
       $article_date = $row_news['article_date'];
       $article_author = $row_news['article_author'];
       $article_keywords = $row_news['article_keywords'];
       $article_content = $row_news['article_content'];
       $article_image = $row_news['article_image'];


   }

   echo "

    <a href='details.php?article=$article_id'>$article_title</a>

    <div>$article_content <a href='article.php?article=$article_id'>Read More</a></div><br />

    <img src='images/$article_image' width='100' height='100'/>




    ";

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Because when you're setting those variables in your `while` loop, you're __overwriting__ the values that you set for the previous record

Comment: Move the echo() up into the loop, just before the ending brace. :D

Answer (score 1):

Put your output in your while loop so that each record gets placed in the page:

```
while ($row_news=mysql_fetch_array($run_news)){
       $article_id = $row_news['article_id'];
       $article_title = $row_news['article_title'];
       $article_date = $row_news['article_date'];
       $article_author = $row_news['article_author'];
       $article_keywords = $row_news['article_keywords'];
       $article_content = $row_news['article_content'];
       $article_image = $row_news['article_image'];




   echo "<a href='details.php?article=$article_id'>$article_title</a>
         <div>$article_content <a href='article.php?article=$article_id'>Read More</a></div><br />
         <img src='images/$article_image' width='100' height='100'/>";

}
```

You should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

You're also assuming your queries work all of the time and that is just a bad plan. Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Answer (score 0):

you should make echo in while loop, so your code should be:

```
while ($row_news=mysql_fetch_array($run_news)){
       $article_id = $row_news['article_id'];
       $article_title = $row_news['article_title'];
       $article_date = $row_news['article_date'];
       $article_author = $row_news['article_author'];
       $article_keywords = $row_news['article_keywords'];
       $article_content = $row_news['article_content'];
       $article_image = $row_news['article_image'];

 echo "

    <a href='details.php?article=$article_id'>$article_title</a>

    <div>$article_content <a href='article.php?article=$article_id'>Read More</a></div><br />

    <img src='images/$article_image' width='100' height='100'/>




    ";

   }
```